# AS2 crossdomain BitmapData.draw image comes out blank

Tags: flash, draw, actionscript-2, bitmapdata, crossdomain.xml

I'm trying to load an image from another server into my Flash file and then turn it into a bitmap, so I can use it more than once. I used the code [here](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/530/1/Use-the-Same-External-Dynamic-Image-Infinitely/Page1.html). It works within the Flash program, but when I run the .swf in a browser, the bitmap comes out blank (white).

The same problem was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694450/moviecliploader-loadmovie-loads-a-blank-image-with-proper-dimensions), but I've already used `System.security.loadPolicyFile` to load a crossdomain.xml file. That file is set to allow access from all domains. However, the image is still coming out blank.

Using the browser's developer tools, I can see that the both the crossdomain.xml file and the original image file are being downloaded.

Any ideas why it's not working?

You can see the .swf file [here](http://studiofuse.biz/LAO/LAO-Schicchi_Pagliacci-300x600-F.html).

Comment: the swf is loading the image for me - i'm using FF39

Comment: hmm...I've checked it on FF39 (as well as Chrome and Safari) on two Macs running 10.9, and it's not working. To clarify, a few images that I'm not using `draw` on are showing up. But for me, it's showing white under the copy "stars in Woody Allen's Gianni Schicchi". There should be an image there.

Comment: ah you're right it's not displaying for me either.

But I also can't see any requests for that other file or any crossdomain reqeusts.

just requests for the 2 images that are loading.

Comment: Interesting. You're right; neither FF nor Vivaldi show the images or crossdomain.xml file in Network—but Chrome does. Anyway, the clown image under "Pagliacci" is also crossdomain (which is showing in FF), but I'm just using the JPEG as-is. Anyway, thanks for looking into it. But unless you're still interested in solving the problem, don't worry about it—I've reworked the .swf so a bunch of smaller images are hosted and the "bed" image is included in the file.

Comment: no problem, I'm happy to leave it if you've changed tack.